# R Jupyter notebook in Mac doesn't display some errors

Tags: r, macos, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I installed R, Anaconda and Jupyter on a Mac (OSX El Capitan). While everything else works well, I've noticed the Jupyter Notebooks doesn't display some error messages, at least some of the errors from ggplot2 and Dplyr.

For instance the following R code is incorrect:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))
```

And on the terminal I get the following error:

```
Error: Mapping should be created with `aes() or `aes_()`.
```

But R on Jupyter doesn't display any error.